# Setup Raspberry Pi 3 as bluetooth remote controller AVRCP no media streaming

Tags: raspbian

I want to setup my Raspberry Pi as media remote controller only. I want to see song name and be able to skip tracks. But I do not want media to be streamed to it. I want host device to stream media. Is this possible? I have followed this guide and it is perfect otherwise but it also streams media to raspberry...

[Setup Raspberry Pi 3 as bluetooth speaker](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47708/setup-raspberry-pi-3-as-bluetooth-speaker)

Tero

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is best managed by using **UPnP**. The answer does not exactly matches what you asked but it shows how it may be done with media standards and the option to build it up step by step, e.g. playing same music in many rooms using a Raspberry Pi and control it from your pocket.

You have to setup a system that consists of a **Media Server**, some (at least one) **Media Renderer** and a **Control Point**. With this components you can attach a media renderer to music boxes for output. With the control point you can manage what music getting from the media server is to play on the media renderer. You can also select what media renderer to use.

For example I use a built-in UPnP media server on my internet router (an additional goodie).

As control point I use an App on my android phone, named **DroidUPnP**. But there are some other Apps usable as control point, e.g. **BubbleUpNP**. But I don't like it because its a heavy weight and do much more than I need (only control the media renderer).

And finally to come to **Raspberry Pi** you can use it as a **Media Renderer**. How to setup it you can look at [Howto install DLNA media renderer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79005/79866).

Comment: This does not seem to be a bluetooth solution, so it does not work for me. I am using raspberry with Android device through. bluetooth not wifi.