# Multiroom audio from input source

Tags: audio, home-automation

I want to build a multiroom audio solution based on Rpi and Snapcast (the best solution I've seen up to now).

I found lot of articles, tutorials, samples how to build such a system to play audio from files, Spotify or whatever service or storage. However, my primary goal is to share sound from my TV across the rooms. So I want to connect my TV with the Rpi with Snapcast server running by wire (jack or optical) and cast the sound to all Snapcast clients (and controll it from HomeAssistant, but thats the next chapter). And, if possible, to have also direct audio output from the server.

I was not able to find any suitable example of such a setup. It looks like it is not a simple deal to work with audio input on Rpi.

Could you please provide something to read or, better, some experience? Or it will never work?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is by far to broad. Note that we are not a discussion style forum and open ended invitations to brainstorm are not appropriate to the format. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Hey, I know my question is not precisely targeted. Perhaps if I know how to ask better I would be able to google a solution. As I don't know the exact terminology I hope someone more experienced will answer "This is a piece of cake, look here...." and I will find out how to call the technology I am actually requesting.

Comment: You want to investigate pulseaudio and/or alsa.  Pretty sure you can just pipe /dev/audio or /dev/dsp (or /dev something) the same way `cat` is used with a file here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Snapcast#Audio_source

Comment: I'm also working on a multi room media solution (audio and video) but it is far away from giving working examples. Some keywords for my attempts are upnp, dlna, multicast, media-server, media-render, controlpoint, kodi. The only what I have documented so far is [Howto install DLNA media renderer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79005/79866).