# How to control PulsAudio programmatically?

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to set up my Raspberry Pi as Bluetooth-Audio-Receiver which transports the audio via AUX to my speakers. I've read that there is PulseAudio which would solve my problem. But I want to be able to connect to this Raspberry Pi with multiple (2-3) smartphones simultaneously. So I need a program on the Raspberry which decides which source should be used. And I want also to be able to set the volume and equalize the audio (#Bassboost).

Which programming language: It doesn't matter

I'm a beginner on Raspberry Pi,
I'm happy about each answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a mediarenderer together with a controlpoint. I cannot say if it is the right program for your setup because lack of additional information. But it is worth to have a look at it. It is needed that the media sources (different smartphones?) announce themselves as media server by uPNP/DLNA on your local network. I know apps that do it (bubbleUPNP?). Now with the controlpoint, an app on the smartphone, you can select the media server you want to have as source. Maybe it is also doable with bubbleUPNP? Have a look at [Howto install DLNA media renderer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79005/79866) and for some background information [DLNA server, ad-hoc wi-fi, and connection with an Android DAC player](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114621/79866).